# Is it possible to prevent pacemaker from stopping resource in old node, while starting the resource in new node?

Tags: pacemaker

we collect heap dumps of the resource on failed node, before restarting the resource.

However, to minimize the downtime (as heapdump collection taking time), I'm checking if it is possible to start the resource in new node, without stopping it in the old node.

I could think of some dirty tricks that might work if the stop script uses a pid file to stop the process. But if monitoring of the resouce is successful, then it gets more complicated, as the resource gets blocked etc. etc.

So, is there any option in pacemaker itself to move resources and telling cluster not to stop a specific resource.

I thought the following is possible, but didn't work:

-> make the resource unmanaged by cluster
-> make active node standby (all resources always runs in same node for our case)
-> Now I expected, all resources to start again in the new node (with the unmanaged resource to not start), so that I could start it manually with pcs resource debug-start.

However, it didn't work as the particular resource is part of a resource group and it blocks the whole resource group from moving to new node.

Any ideas?

Comment: pacemaker only execute the resource agent, this one need to take care of the logic of your application, in the stop function you can return SUCCESS if your application is dumping

Comment: wow..yes..thanks..I wil try this